# How to use --wait with post-install hook in helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I use an install script in a post-install hook.
When I run helm install with --wait option, helm waits that all pods are ready, but helm does not launch post-install hooks script.
Then, the pods are not yet ready (pods are waiting for install script to finish).

I tried with pre-install hook instead, but the install script needs other services to be running...

PS: it works fine if I don't use "--wait", but CI from gitlab won't fail if there is an error during pod startups.

Is there a way to run the post-install hooks during the helm install --wait period?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can solve your problem with Helm [post-install hook](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/), but you may with vanilla Kubernetes [jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) or perhaps [hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/), i.e. running job/hook along with your deployment that will depend only on Kubernetes.

One of the first things to try is to remove `helm.sh/hook` annotations from your existing job.

```
  annotations:
    # This is what defines this resource as a hook. Without this line, the
    # job is considered part of the release.
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
```

Helm can then wait for them to finish as they will be executed by Kubernetes.

Comment: unfortunately, if I remove the "install" hook, the install script will be launched at upgrades too...

Comment: Just throwing two idea here: Is it not possible to use some kind of persistent storage to store the state of the script - installed / not installed? 
Or check with the script if given resource/object is present before executing?

Comment: In a similar situation, I wrapped the job in a `{{- if .Release.IsInstall -}}`. That way it is only created during the initial install - not on subsequent upgrades. See https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delete policy

```yaml
annotations:
    # This is what defines this resource as a hook. Without this line, the
    # job is considered part of the release.
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-10"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded , hook-failed , before-hook-creation
```